# Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake

Tags: linux, qtcreator, cmake

Как успокоить cmake удовлетворив зависимости?

```
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.7 (using /usr/bin/qmake-qt4)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found KDE 4.12 include dir: /usr/include
-- Found KDE 4.12 library dir: /usr/lib
-- Found the KDE4 kconfig_compiler preprocessor: /usr/bin/kconfig_compiler
-- Found automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.7 (using /usr/bin/qmake-qt4)
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1094 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:218 (kde4_add_library)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:255 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:284 (add_import_export_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:268 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:287 (add_datablocks_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:273 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:290 (add_database_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:897 (kde4_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:273 (kde4_add_unit_test)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:290 (add_database_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:179 (get_directory_property):
  Policy CMP0059 is not set: Do no treat DEFINITIONS as a built-in directory
  property.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0059" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/automoc4/Automoc4Config.cmake:243 (_add_automoc4_target)
  /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:1038 (_automoc4_kde4_pre_target_handling)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:339 (kde4_add_executable)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/MacroOptionalAddSubdirectory.cmake:38 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes/doc

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/alexandr/krecipes/doc

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (macro_optional_add_subdirectory)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at doc/CMakeLists.txt:1 (add_subdirectory):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes/doc/uk

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/alexandr/krecipes/doc/uk

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:311 (add_custom_target):
  Policy CMP0002 is not set: Logical target names must be globally unique.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0002" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  doc/uk/CMakeLists.txt:1 (kde4_create_handbook)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at doc/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_subdirectory):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes/doc/sv

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/alexandr/krecipes/doc/sv

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:311 (add_custom_target):
  Policy CMP0002 is not set: Logical target names must be globally unique.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0002" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  doc/sv/CMakeLists.txt:1 (kde4_create_handbook)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at doc/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_subdirectory):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes/doc/en_US

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/alexandr/krecipes/doc/en_US

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:311 (add_custom_target):
  Policy CMP0002 is not set: Logical target names must be globally unique.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0002" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  doc/en_US/CMakeLists.txt:1 (kde4_create_handbook)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at doc/CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_subdirectory):
  Policy CMP0013 is not set: Duplicate binary directories are not allowed.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0013" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The binary directory

    /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes/doc/pt_BR

  is already used to build a source directory.  This command uses it to build
  source directory

    /home/alexandr/krecipes/doc/pt_BR

  which can generate conflicting build files.  CMake does not support this
  use case but it used to work accidentally and is being allowed for
  compatibility.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/KDE4Macros.cmake:311 (add_custom_target):
  Policy CMP0002 is not set: Logical target names must be globally unique.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0002" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  doc/pt_BR/CMakeLists.txt:1 (kde4_create_handbook)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alexandr/build-krecipes-4_8_7_x64-debug-krecipes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake жалуется не на зависимости, а на соприкосновение с политикой [CMP0059](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0059.html).

Пропишите следующую строку в начале своего `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0059 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0013 OLD)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 OLD)
```

Вообще, «политики» — это способ сохранения обратной совместимости между различными версиями CMake. Как только в какой-то существующий функционал вносятся изменения, вводится политика, позволяющая выбирать между старым поведением и новым. По умолчанию выбирается старое поведение и выводится предупреждение о необходимости совершения явного выбора.

В данном случае речь идёт о том, что до версии 3.3 список препроцессорных объявлений был виден только при нахождении не выше папки с `CMakeLists.txt`, добавившим соответствующие объявления. В новых же версиях все объявления, похоже, стали глобальными.

Comment: вписал: 

     cmake_policy(SET CMP0059 NEW)
     cmake_policy(SET CMP0013 NEW)
     cmake_policy(SET CMP0002 NEW)
     cmake_policy(SET CMP0000 NEW)

правильно ли я поступил? Вывод работы программы изменился.

Comment: @shaman888, судя по тому, что сборочный скрипт использует зарезервированные имена и многократное упоминание одних и тех же папок, для `CMP0013` и `CMP0002` стоит задать значение `OLD`.

Comment: @shaman888, для `CMP0059` я задал `NEW` потому, что старое поведение вообще планируется к удалению в будущих версиях CMake (`The OLD behavior of a policy is deprecated by definition and may be removed in a future version of CMake.`).

Comment: почему вы не упомянули CMP0000? Без вписания cmake_policy(SET CMP0000 OLD) работа завершалась ошибкой.

Comment: @Arhad гляньте правку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/211546